# High JVM Heap utilisation affecting JStack

Tags: java, memory, jvm, jstack

I have a question regarding usage between JVM and Jstack

If there is high jvm heap utilisation, let's say over 90 percent does that have any correlation between jstack responding jvm

Would it affect the Jstack in anyway

Answer (score 0):

In general i don't think Jstack have anything to do with memory utilization, it's used to get threaddumps and stack traces.

But i have seen sometimes if JVM is not responding for any reason such as Out of memory issue, it will not respond Jstack as well, you can use kill -3 to take thread dumps.